# Difference between .asm and .asm.1?

Tags: modeling, file-type, autodesk, file-conversion

I am attempting to open a file in Fusion Autodesk that is saved as a .asm.1 file. Fusion Autodesk says it works with .asm files, and I am confused as to what the difference is or if there is a way to convert from .asm.1 to .asm so that I can work with this file in the software?

Answer (score 0):

file.asm is an assembly language source code file.
file.asm1 is associated to Apple operating system.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).